# How to re-order DIVs randomly using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, random

I am trying to have a number of DIVs show up on page load but appear in a random order each time – but not entirely random as I would like them to abide by some rules.

There are two different types of DIVs:

1. Cards x5 (C)
2. Image x4 (I)

The rules should be as follows:

1. The first DIV must always be a C type
2. Remaining DIVs should alternate between I and C
   (e.g. C, I, C, I, C, I, C, I, C)
3. All DIVs should be randomly selected from their respective type

I've tried an array shuffle using jQuery from the solution to another problem (below), but that just puts the DIVs in a random order, not taking into account rules 1 and 2.

```js
var $cont = $('#content');
var itemsArr = $cont.children().get();

$cont.append(shuffle(itemsArr));

function shuffle(a) {
  var j, x, i;
  for (i = a.length; i; i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
    x = a[i - 1];
    a[i - 1] = a[j];
    a[j] = x;
  }
  return a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="content">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="card1">Card #1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="card2">Card #2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="card3">Card #3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="card4">Card #4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="card5">Card #5</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="image1">Image #1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="image2">Image #2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="image3">Image #3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="image4">Image #4</div>
</div>
```

Would be eternally grateful for any suggestions or help to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rough idea is to remove the elements from DOM, shuffle them and append to original parent:

```js
function shuffle(array) {
  // Fisher-Yates shuffle
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    let temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
}
$(function() {
  let cards = $("#content > [id^=card]").remove().get();
  let images = $("#content > [id^=image]").remove().get();
  shuffle(cards);
  shuffle(images);
  for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    $("#content").append(cards[i]);
    if (i < images.length) {
      $("#content").append(images[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font: medium monospace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="content">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="card1">Card #1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="card2">Card #2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="card3">Card #3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="card4">Card #4</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="card5">Card #5</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="image1">Image #1</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="image2">Image #2</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="image3">Image #3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4" id="image4">Image #4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works beautifully and is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much for your help – and in record time too!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [non-JQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/) example. It shuffles both cards and images and subsequently re-appends them cf the pattern you want. No need for element removal, because the elements are moved by the `append` operation anyway.

By the way: in your html `div#image5` is missing ...

```js
const shuffle = array => {
  const swap = (i1, i2) => [array[i1], array[i2]] = [array[i2], array[i1]];
  return (Array(array.length).fill(0)
    .forEach( (_, i) => swap(i, Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1)))), array);
};

const content = document.querySelector(`#content`);
const cards = shuffle([...content.querySelectorAll(`[id^=card]`)]);
const images = shuffle([...content.querySelectorAll(`[id^=image]`)]);
cards.forEach( (card, i) => content.append(card, images[i] ?? ``) );
```

```css
body {
  font: medium monospace;
}

[id^="image"] {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="content">
  <div id="card1">Card #1</div>
  <div id="card2">Card #2</div>
  <div id="card3">Card #3</div>
  <div id="card4">Card #4</div>
  <div id="card5">Card #5</div>
  <div id="image1">Image #1</div>
  <div id="image2">Image #2</div>
  <div id="image3">Image #3</div>
  <div id="image4">Image #4</div>
</div>
```